# Change git branch type

Tags: git, bitbucket

I searched how to change a branch name and found the commands below:

```
git branch -m new-name
git branch -m old-name new-name
```

What's the problem? The problem is that created branches aside our pattern, for example:

[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]

The pattern was to select a brach type.

At first I thought with a just new name of the branch it would fix it but I'm not sure, and when I searched about change the branch type, my search was inconclusive.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Already answered, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A branch in Git does not have a type, only a *name*. Depending on project policy you might structure your branch (names) hierarchically, by prefixing them with `feature/` or `bugfix/`, but that's just an arbitrary prefix.

If you want to create a branch called `feature/mybranch`, then do just that: `git branch -m feature/mybranch` to rename your current branch, or `git checkout -b feature/mybranch starting-ref` to create a new branch with this name off an existing ref.